# Calculating multiple averages across different parts of the table?

Tags: sql, hive, cube, rollup, grouping-sets

I have the following `transactions` table:

```
customer_id purchase_date   product         category        department      quantity    store_id
    1       2020-10-01      Kit Kat         Candy           Food                2       store_A
    1       2020-10-01      Snickers        Candy           Food                1       store_A
    1       2020-10-01      Snickers        Candy           Food                1       store_A
    2       2020-10-01      Snickers        Candy           Food                2       store_A
    2       2020-10-01      Baguette        Bread           Food                5       store_A
    2       2020-10-01      iPhone          Cell phones     Electronics         2       store_A
    3       2020-10-01      Sony PS5        Games           Electronics         1       store_A
```

I would like to calculate the average number of products purchased (for each `product` in the table). I'm also looking to calculate averages across each `category` and each `department` by accounting for all products within the same `category` or `department` respectively. Care should be taken to divide over **unique customers** AND the product `quantity` being greater than 0 (a 0 quantity indicates a refund, and should not be accounted for).

So basically, the output table would like below:

[image]

...where `store_id` and `average_level_type` are partition columns.

Is there a way to achieve this in a single pass over the transactions table? or do I need to break down my approach into multiple steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Or you using Oracle or Hive?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @alhazen . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using -- someone with your reputation should know how to tag questions properly.

Comment: It is for Hive.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using “union all” as below -

```
Select store_id, 'product' as average_level_type,product as id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity,
Count(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_count, sum(quantity)/count(distinct customer_id) as average
from transactions
where quantity > 0
group by store_id,product
Union all
Select store_id, 'category' as average_level_type, category as id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity,
Count(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_count, sum(quantity)/count(distinct customer_id) as average
from transactions
where quantity > 0
group by store_id,category
Union all
Select store_id, 'department' as average_level_type,department as id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity,
Count(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_count, sum(quantity)/count(distinct customer_id) as average
from transactions
where quantity > 0
group by store_id,department;
```

If you want to avoid using union all in that case you can use something like rollup() or group by grouping sets() to achieve the same but the query would be a little more complicated to get the output in the exact format which you have shown in the question.

EDIT : Below is how you can use grouping sets to get the same output -

```
Select store_id,
       case when G_ID = 3 then 'product' 
            when G_ID = 5 then 'category'
            when G_ID = 6 then 'department' end As average_level_type,
       case when G_ID = 3 then product 
            when G_ID = 5 then category
            when G_ID = 6 then department end As id,
       total_quantity,
       unique_customer_count,
       average
from            
    (select store_id, product, category, department, sum(quantity) as total_quantity, Count(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_count, sum(quantity)/count(distinct customer_id) as average, GROUPING__ID As G_ID
    from transactions
    group by store_id,product,category,department
    grouping sets((store_id,product),(store_id,category),(store_id,department))
    ) Tab
order by 2    
;
```

Comment: @alhazen - The above approach work for you? Please share comments/thoughts.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the union approach. I'll check out grouping sets. Thanks.

Comment: @alhazen - See my edit above. I have added how to write the query using grouping sets function to get the desired output.

Comment: Looks great! thank you. Do you know how to adapt the query so that the results are written to an output table whose partition columns are `store_id` and `average_level_type`?

Comment: I made an error in my question. The average for each category is per department/category, and not global category.

Comment: @alhazen - The table in which you want to insert the output/results of the query above, while creating that table (in the DDL statement) you have to define the partition columns using Hive syntax. I can update my answer to add that syntax for your reference.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, would recommend you to create a new question. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm familiar with the syntax to create a partitioned table. I'm wondering how will your query will work, writing to multiple partitions dynamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223420/discussion-between-somy-and-alhazen).