# Combining OVER (PARTITION BY...) with GROUPING SETS?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, rollup, grouping-sets

I have the following `transaction` table:

[image]

I would like to calculate the total quantity purchased for each:

- `product`
- `category` (i.e. total quantity of all products within the same `category`)
- `department` (i.e. total quantity of all products within the same `department`)

In addition, the above totals should be computed:

1. per individual shopper
2. per family/household (Sum of total quantities for all shoppers in the same family).

The output table should look like:

[image]

For the family, the totals are calculated once and then "copied" to each shopper in the same household.

To calculate the multiple totals for `product`/`category`/`department` across the table, I'm using `GROUPING SETS` as pointed out to me in an [earlier question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64456712/1700998). So I got the `total_quantity_individual` right.

For `total_quantity_family`, it would make sense to use `OVER(PARTITION BY)` as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64687823/1700998) on a much simpler table.

However, I'm not sure how to combine both together. There's not much information out there on combining `OVER(PARTITION BY)` with `GROUPING SETS`.

My query looks like:

```sql
SELECT
    family_id,
    shopper_id,
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 6 THEN 'department'
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 5 THEN 'category'
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 3 THEN 'product'
    END AS total_level_type,
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 6 THEN department
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 5 THEN category
        WHEN GROUPING__ID = 3 THEN product
    END AS id,
    SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity_shopper
    -- sum(sum(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, product) AS total_quantity_family
FROM
    transaction
GROUP BY
    family_id, 
    shopper_id,
    product,
    category,
    department
    GROUPING SETS (
        (family_id, shopper_id, product),
        (family_id, shopper_id, category),
        (family_id, shopper_id, department)
    )
ORDER BY
  total_level_type;
```

If `OVER(PARTITION BY)` does not work for my case, my other options might be:

1. Group `transaction` by `family_id`, then run GROUPING SETS on the result, then join back with `transaction`.
2. Maybe a trick using explode() and lateral view?

I really don't want to separate out the queries between the individual vs family versions for maintainability reasons.

Note: I'm using Spark SQL with Hive context if that helps.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Edit: This seems to work:

```sql
...
SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity_shopper,
CASE        
    WHEN GROUPING__ID = 6 THEN sum(sum(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, department)
    WHEN GROUPING__ID = 5 THEN sum(sum(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, category)
    WHEN GROUPING__ID = 3 THEN sum(sum(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, product)
END AS total_quantity_family
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple `sum() over()` with different `partition by` clause:

```sql
select
  family_id,
  shopper_id,
  total_level_type,
  id,
  total_quantity_individual,
  total_quantity_family
from
(
  select 
      family_id, 
      shopper_id,
      array(
        NAMED_STRUCT('id', product, 
                     'total_level_type', 'product',
                     'total_quantity_individual', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, shopper_id, product),
                     'total_quantity_family', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, product)
                     ),
        NAMED_STRUCT('id', category, 
                     'total_level_type', 'category',
                     'total_quantity_individual', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, shopper_id, category),
                     'total_quantity_family', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, category)
                     ),
        NAMED_STRUCT('id', department, 
                     'total_level_type', 'department', 
                     'total_quantity_individual', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, shopper_id, department),
                     'total_quantity_family', sum(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY family_id, department)
                     )
      ) AS array_structs
  from
    transaction
)
lateral view inline(array_structs) exploded
order by
  total_level_type
```

Comment: I adapted your query, but can't edit your post for some reason.

Comment: The final table contains multiple transactions for the same family_id, shopper_id, product. Example ("A, 1, "Kit Kat") appears twice (though the totals are correct). So a group by is necessary I think.

Comment: Ok updated your post. However, I couldn't get the GROUP BY to work.